# any Hitech Reverse ND Grad users out there?

Tags: hitech, nd-filter, graduated-filters

I just received my new Hitech Reverse ND Grad 0.9 today ... and it doesn't look like reverse at all .. I tried putting on a white paper .. it just look like a normal ND Hard Grad filter .. I tried looking through my window .. I can't see any difference in the middle bit and top bit .. I looked through the view finder it shows no difference between bottom bit and top bit. This is my first Reverse ND Grad but I already own few ND Hard and Soft Grad.

On the receipt it does say "Hitech 100x150mm ND reverse Grad 0.9" and even on the filter .. it says "ND 0.9 RG" ... i assume RG means Reverse Graduated ... Are there any use experience that before ? or Did i receive a wrong/defect item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it doesn't look like this, then it is not a reverse grad.

[image: Hitech Reverse ND Grad]

Found at 2filter.com, http://www.2filter.com/prices/Hitech/HitechReverseGradual.html

Comment: No .. there is no difference between the top and middle shaded bit of the filter. It is just like ND Hard Grad filter. if it is the reverse ND grad filter then I should clearly see the difference if I just look at the filter right?

Comment: Yeah, you should at least see a lighter area at the very top edge. If the filter itself is marked as a RG, then it sounds like a manufacturing issue. They should replace that no problem.

Comment: hey .. sorry I lost my account ... I am now logging in with google account and I don't know where is the above account ... thanks for help ..

Comment: Hi @LaurenceNyein. I've merged your old account into the new one you created. You should have a single account now, with "Laurence Nyein" as the username.